# How can i remove index from json?

Tags: javascript, php, laravel

this is my response :

[image]

i want to remove index(0,1,2,3,4,5,6) from my response and want response like below :

```
{date: "2022-12-14", verify: 0, unverify: 0}

{date: "2022-12-13", verify: 1, unverify: 1}

{date: "2022-12-12", verify: 0, unverify: 0}

{date: "2022-12-11", verify: 0, unverify: 0}

{date: "2022-12-10", verify: 0, unverify: 0}

{date: "2022-12-09", verify: 0, unverify: 0}

{date: "2022-12-08", verify: 0, unverify: 0}
```

Comment: Why don't you add the response as text to the question?
Anyway, you can try this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21919781/how-to-ignore-specific-values-when-applying-json-encode-to-class

Comment: That is just how the browser shows an array. You cannot remove those indexes because they aren't part of the data.

Comment: try `json_encode(array_values(json_decode($yourArray)))`

Answer (score 0):

You can't remove those indexes because those are representing keys for each element in the array (because you have more objects in there). If you need to go over the JSON response just use

`foreach($jsonResponse as $key => $response)`

This way, each $response will represent one of the objects you have and the key will contain indexes you want to remove.

You could also try `json_encode(array_values(json_decode($response)))` but I think that foreach will do the trick for you.